# Zero values getting inserted in the database table

Tags: php, mysql, insert

This is the piece of code which I'm using to open up a pop up window with the variable $query_string which is being used to save the entries made in the form.

```
    echo'<script language = "JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        window.open(\'./save.php?'.$query_string.'\',\'save\',\'location=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes\');
```

Then i have used to save.php to display a submit button and written an insert statement to put the data into the database.The problem is the rows are getting populated with 0 in the database table.Any mistakes committed?

```
        if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit") 
        {
            //appending the date to store in the database.
            $entry_date_array = array($_REQUEST["year"],$_REQUEST["month"],$_REQUEST["day"]);
            $entry_date = implode('-', $entry_date_array);
            echo "$entry_date";
            //appending aggr nr and fetching the id from the database.
            $aggr_nr = $_REQUEST['list_nr_01'].$_REQUEST['list_nr_02'].$_REQUEST['list_nr_03'];
            $sql="SELECT v.id FROM aggregatenumber AS v WHERE v.aggr_nr = '".$aggr_nr."'";//missing Quotes
            $aggr_id = @mysql_query($sql);
            $result = @mysql_fetch_array($aggr_id);
            $test= $result['id'];
            echo "$test";


        $sql_einl_sp = "INSERT INTO search_parts(entry_date,aggr_nr)values('".$entry_date."','".$test."')";
        $result_einl_sp = @mysql_query($sql_einl_sp);
```

Html

```
    <body>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
        <h>Save Information</h>
    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="submit" name="btncancel" value="Cancel"/>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: Maybe error in your sql syntax. Remove @ symbol before each function, that may show you an error

Comment: I did that..No error messages are coming up.

Comment: check using `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$sql_einl_sp = "INSERT INTO search_parts(entry_date,aggr_nr)
                  values('".$entry_date."','".$test."')";
```

To

```
$sql_einl_sp = "INSERT INTO search_parts(entry_date,aggr_nr)
                 values('".$entry_date."',".$test.")";
```

Comment: I commented the query and tried to see if the page is able to just display the values in $entry_date and $test which it gets from the form.The values don't come up so i guess the issue has to be before the query execution.

Answer (score 1):

Try printing the query to see what exactly goes to the database.

It may possible that the variables in query are empty or 0, or
you may not have correctly defined the datatypes in table for this particular fields.

Comment: the variables in the query are empty.I think it has got to do with the $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] for the submit button.